# macOS Quicklook in finder renders images without antialias / jagged edges

Tags: finder, preview, quicklook

I have a very annoying bug in finder: when i select an image, then first the quicklook image preview looks terrible, jagged edges, no antialias, but after resizing it gets smooth again. It is especially bad with higher resolution images. 
I have this problem since the Yosemite update, and it never healed ever since. I am on Mojave currently.
Since i have not found any kind of options to tweak the rendering settings of the images i honestly run out of options, except of a clean install..
Do you have any tipps, how to get the quicklook image generator reset to factory settings to work properly?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen to all pictures including photos, or only to some?

Comment: it happenes to all pictures, png, jpeg, etc. but not with pdf-s.